# Problem with identify command in Mac OS X

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, libraries

I'm trying to do the following

> identify somefile.jpg

and I get the following:

```
identify

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Trace/BPT trap
```

Do you know how to resolve this? BTW, I have Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`identify` is part of MacPorts or fink or similar. You probably built your code on one architecture, migrated to a new machine, but didn't rebuild your MacPorts/fink/whatever code. Do a "clean" and re-build everything.

For macports first try:

`$ sudo port selfupdate`

If that doesn't work them it might be easiest to just uninstall macports and start again. See  http://guide.macports.org/ for details of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Could you please advise how to clean and rebuild everything? I use MacPorts

Comment: @Tam: I've added info for macports to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have resolved it! it might have been that I recovered my Leopard System from Time Machine to Snow Leopard and it copied old files.